# Scratch parameter passing byref or byval

Tags: mit-scratch

In scratch I am building a recursive routine that I want to avoid using global variables with. At the moment I am having some issues with parameter passing and need to know whether they are passed to subroutines as ByVal or ByRef and can you change the method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Scratch routine variables can't be returned and there is no way to set them to a different value, so that is irrelevant.

The routine block allows you to name an input variable, but not to then use it in a set block, and there's no return block at all.

[image: Routine block]

You can't change it in Scratch, but you can I believe in byob.

Comment: In case someone else who, like me, would take 3 readings to finally get it; the simple answer to the question is **ByVal** (with the added favc that the routine parameters would be immutable).

Answer (score 0):

There is a way around the problem boisvert is showing in the other anwer.
Drag `number1` to where `0` is and it will set `testvar` to `number1` for other sprites to use.

You still can't modify the original `number1` though.

Comment: Yes, you can use a different variable, which will have global scope. But that isn't the initial question.

Comment: His picture made me think that when he said "can't use it in a set block", he meant "can't set testvar equal to it". But you're right. Should I delete the answer or just upvote your comment?

Comment: I've edited your answer to keep the best parts of it.